# Can I still revive my poor black prince?

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health, ficus

I got this black prince almost a yr ago. I initially kept it indoors but eventually put it outside (east facing with direct morning sun) where it thrived and grew well. I placed it back inside but observed that the new sprout is not opening so I decided to put it outside again for 1 day but the lower leaves somehow got burned.

So I brought it inside again. Initially it lost its burned leaves but the upper half still has healthy looking leaves. However, recently all leaves have become really droopy and they're just coming off. The new leaf has not unfurled as well.

I have already moved it back to it's original place outside when it was very healthy but I'm worried it might eventually die.

What else can I do?

***please see below image
[image]

It only has 3 leaves the very last one to unfurl did not even fully expanded like the others. Should I prune it then transfer to a new pot?

Comment: can you add a picture?

Comment: Which format does this accept? I trued uploading jpg and even png but it does not seem to work. You can try this one: https://icedrive.net/dashboard/#/cloud

Comment: It's not the format, jpg and png are accepted, it is the size of the photo, if you are using a cell phone you need to reduce the size of the photo. If it's less than 1 or Mb it should work